# Git-config setting to specify --include-untracked for git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I understand git stash, but I find the default behavior of ignoring my untracked files to be rarely what I want.  If I'm working on new code and want to stash it, I want `git stash` to save my entire state and leave me with a clean working folder, and `git stash apply` to bring it all back.

The default behavior doesn't do this because it leaves untracked files lying around, which is rarely what I want.

Q: Is there a git config setting that will tell `git stash` to always `--include-untracked`?

I know I can create a git alias to do this...I'm specifically asking whether there is a config setting (I didn't find one mentioned in the documentation of git-stash.)

Thanks!

Comment: "*I didn't find one mentioned in the documentation of `git-stash`*" Why do you think there're hidden, undocumented settings?

Comment: You can pass the `-u` flag instead of the verbose `--include-untracked`. Or create an alias. Not seeing a config option for this. Or submit a PR for git.

Comment: @phd - my assumption or hope was that my search was flawed.